# Specifying cells and sheets in formula using VBA

Tags: vba, formula

I need my macro to input the following formula:

```
Worksheets("U_NEDC_COLD_online_0").Cells(3, A).formula = "=IF(" & Worksheets (U_NEDC_COLD_online_0).Cells(3, AA).Value & "=" & Worksheets(U_NEDC_COLD_online).Cells(3, AA).Value & ";" & Worksheets(U_NEDC_COLD_online).Cells(3, A).Value & ";" & Worksheets(U_NEDC_COLD_online_0).Cells(3, A).Value & ")"
```

I've also tried the same formula with the `".Address"` property and it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

The final formula should look like this:

```
=IF($AA3 = U_NEDC_COLD_online!$AA3; U_NEDC_COLD_online!A3; U_NEDC_COLD_online_0!A3)
```

PS:  Worksheets("U_NEDC_COLD_online_0")  is not the same as Worksheets(U_NEDC_COLD_online_0). (its not a typo)

Thanks.

Comment: Exactly what in the [`Address`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/HV080553416.aspx) property does not work?

Comment: I get the same "Run time error '1004' "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use commas instead of semicolons to separate the arguments of the IF statement.
2. Your formula appears to have a circular relationship; the formula is going into cell A3 and references cell A3... I'll leave that to you to work out.
3. Always use `Option Explicit`. Once you put that line at the top of your module, you'll get the error: `Variable not defined` for the variables: A, AA, and possibly `U_NEDC_COLD_online` and `U_NEDC_COLD_online_0`  that you probably intended to use as string literals. (see next bullet for a workaround)
4. If `U_NEDC_COLD_online_0` is truly a variable/constant name and is not equal to the string literal that you use elsewhere (e.g. `U_NEDC_COLD_online_0`), you should really change the variable name to something else!
5. If the only reason you are dynamically building the formula is to accommodate variable row indexes, use this where the 3 can be replaced by a variable:

   `Worksheets("U_NEDC_COLD_online_0").Cells(3, 1).Formula = "=IF($AA" & 3 & "=" & "U_NEDC_COLD_online!AA" & 3 & ", U_NEDC_COLD_online!A" & 3 & ", A" & 3 & ")"`
6. If you don't even need variable row indexes, just use this:

   `Worksheets("U_NEDC_COLD_online_0").Range(A3).Formula = "=IF($AA3=U_NEDC_COLD_online!AA3, U_NEDC_COLD_online!A3, A3)"`